# How to use firebase app multiple times in reactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, user-interface

I am trying to use ReactJS and make a firebase app with a user interface but when I try to do the register and login separately I am getting the error of a duplicate app. I want to know how I can import the firebase credentials like the API key and etc, so I can use firebase essentially in different pages like a `registration.js` or a `login.js`

I have tried importing but I am not sure how to do that exactly because I am not familiar with firebase on ReactJS

I am trying to use firebase credentials multiple times in my project and in multiple files and I am trying to pull the API key and config credentials more than once and I am wondering on how to do that or how to set up my firebase/app file

thank you

Comment: A search shows lots of relevant links: [Firebase on ReactJS](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+on+ReactJS). For multiple projects: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application? If you can't get that to work, edit your question to include the [minimal code that shows where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thank you I just have to have a secondary and so forth "config" to initialize the app, thank you.